# Where in FFmpeg is the DTS decoder located?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

Where is the actual DTS decoder located?

When I search through the FFmpeg folders, `dtsdec.c` and `dtshddec.c` show up, but they're only 2–4 kB, and don't have any actual decoding code anywhere within them, and all the files included are just generic headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DTS is not just "one" audio codec, as there's much more included under that name. As for the DTS audio codec you're probably referring to, this is called *DTS Coherent Acoustics*.

That's where the abbreviation of the files in FFmpeg come from – `dca`.

In that case, look for the `libavcodec/dca*` files, e.g. for decoding into [`dcadec.c`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/dcadec.c).

Comment: Yeah, I realized the DCA thing right after posting, and followed your directions about libavcodec and found 10-12 files related to it, thanks man. :)